# What is the minimal footage of a Kosher Chuppah?

Tags: halacha, marriage, wedding, chupah

Following "[the shape or form of chuppa](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55090/are-there-any-halachic-reccomendations-or-prohibitions-regarding-the-shape-or-fo)":

Halachicly speaking, Chuppah makes Nissuin - the start of the formal obligations of both sides.

What is the minimal footage of a Kosher Chuppah? A square Tefach, Amah, 4x4 Amah?
What Chuppah size would not constitute Nissuin?

Note, I'm aware of [other approaches to Chuppah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuppah#History_and_legal_aspects), but here I talk about the standard contemporary accepted ones.

Answer (score -1):

I was thinking firstly to compare it to a Succah, inferring its footage from double the footage of a Kosher Succah minus a table (namely 2 times Ama by Ama or 6 Tfochim by 12 Tfochim), but I couldn't find a definitive obligation of standing underneath for the couple.

As I answered [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109983/15579), it appears that the purpose of the current Chuppah we have, is to signal to the crowd the exact place of the wedding procedure. THerefore the Chuppah must be clearly visible to all the people present to be visible by all.

While not obligatory, the Chuppah must be sized accordingly, relatively to the footage of the place and the crowd.