# How high can a Kosher Chuppah be?

Tags: halacha, wedding, chupah

I think that our Chuppah resembles [one form of] a Succah - 4 bars and canopy. For a Kosher Succah, 20 Amah high (~10m) is a limit.

Imagine we do a Chuppah between two 5 stories high buildings - can we stretch a cover between their roofs?

What is the height limit for a Kosher Chuppah?

Comment: Who says there is such a thing as a _Kosher Chuppa_? Why must everything have rules? It's simply a way to prevent המקדש בשוק

Comment: @DannySchoemann Or a way to define a Reshut Chatan for her to enter, when everyone is standing outside.

Comment: @DoubleAA- everyone is standing outside except for about 2 dozen people; Rabbis, Witnesses, Photographers, parents and random relatives and friends...

Comment: @Danny no no, outside under the stars. Where weddings used to be and you'd need a temporary dwelling type thing to mark his reshut.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Not far from me in Wolf Halls in Givat Shaul in Jerusalem the Chuppah was made at the public parking lot, and the question of ownership came to R' Elyashiv Z"l. Finally, the municipality made a specific parking Hall's private and the matter was solved.

Answer (score -1):

We discussed my question today in the Kollel:

To answer this it's essential to define the purpose of a Chuppah. Unfortunately, we don't have a clearly defined one, as different Rabbis connect it to different ideas and traditions.

I would argue, that the contemporary Chuppah, as described in Remo (Eh"E 270) serves the only purpose of the public recognition of the couple's intentions. I.g. "if you want to propose and your intentions are true - show it buy stepping under the Chuppah".

Imagine a crowd of hundreds of people, how would they know who's getting married? You raise a tent or just a canopy to signal everybody "it's here", "this couple is getting married".

If so, the tent must be visible to the crowd and associated with the event. I accept the Talmudic claim about the height of a Kosher Succah, that's limited to 20 Ama because beyond this our eyes don't associate it with the place. And therefore assert that in order for a Chuppah to be perceived by the crowd, its height must not pass the 20 Ama limit.

Comment: From the famous Chidushei Al Berko ;)

Comment: @Kazibácsi I stick with "במקום שאין אנשים השתדל להיות איש".